# Totaling sales figures by product type and store in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling to write a statement to pull out sales figures of multiple stores and display them as a summary. I am querying 4 tables here to get all the information I need. It's working fine until I want to pull out sales of certain types of products.

Here's my statement:

```
SELECT 
    s.name, 
    ROUND(SUM(od.price * od.quantity), 2) AS total, 
    SUM(od.quantity) AS items, 
    ROUND(SUM(od.price * od.quantity), 2) / SUM(od.quantity) AS aiv, 
    COUNT(o.serial) AS orders, 
    ROUND(SUM(od.price * od.quantity), 2) / COUNT(o.serial) AS aov, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN p.type = 'B' THEN ROUND(SUM(od.price * od.quantity), 2) ELSE 0 END) AS bikesales 
FROM 
    stores AS s 
JOIN
    orders AS o ON s.name = o.store
JOIN
    order_detail AS od ON o.serial = od.orderid
JOIN 
    products AS p ON od.productid = p.id
WHERE 
    s.live != 0 
    AND o.date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' 
    AND (o.status = 1 OR o.status = 2 OR o.status = 3 OR o.status = 4) 
    AND od.status = 1
GROUP BY 
    s.name
ORDER BY 
    s.name
```

I think it's the grouping that's preventing this from working correctly as the error I get is `Invalid use of group function`, however it's required for the grouping of the store names.

The section that's selecting by product type is here: `SUM(CASE WHEN p.type = 'B' THEN ROUND(sum(od.price*od.quantity),2) END) as bikesales` - i'm trying to get the total of all sales of bikes and displaying it as `bikesales`.

Is this possible?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

It's illegal to nest sum function, try this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN p.type = 'B' THEN ROUND(od.price*od.quantity,2) ELSE 0 END) as bikesales /*Without other ROUND(sum(od.price*od.quantity),2) */
```